# Meteor upgrade to 1.6 from 1.5.4 error

Tags: windows, meteor, upgrade

I have used chocolatey to reinstall meteor on Windows, but when I run meteor update --release 1.6, the following errors appear:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Users\\claud_000\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.6.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\claud_000\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.6.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'rebuild',
1 verbose cli   '--update-binary' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.2
3 info using node@v8.8.1
4 info readInstalled object
5 verbose rebuild path, id [ 'C:\\Users\\claud_000\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\fourseven_scss\\3.13.0\\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\\npm\\node_modules\\meteor\\compileScssBatch\\node_modules\\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\\node_modules\\node-sass',
5 verbose rebuild   'node-sass@3.13.0' ]
6 silly rebuild set [ 'C:\\Users\\claud_000\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\fourseven_scss\\3.13.0\\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\\npm\\node_modules\\meteor\\compileScssBatch\\node_modules\\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\\node_modules\\node-sass' ]
7 info build C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\node_modules\node-sass
8 info lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~preinstall: node-sass@3.13.0
9 info linkStuff node-sass@3.13.0
10 silly linkStuff node-sass@3.13.0 has C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\node_modules as its parent node_modules
11 verbose linkBins node-sass@3.13.0
12 verbose linkBins [ { 'node-sass': 'bin/node-sass' },
12 verbose linkBins   'C:\\Users\\claud_000\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\fourseven_scss\\3.13.0\\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\\npm\\node_modules\\meteor\\compileScssBatch\\node_modules\\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\\node_modules\\.bin',
12 verbose linkBins   false ]
13 verbose linkMans node-sass@3.13.0
14 verbose rebuildBundles node-sass@3.13.0
15 info lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~install: node-sass@3.13.0
16 verbose lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
17 verbose lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~install: PATH: C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;D:\ANDROID\SDK;D\PYTHON27\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;D:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;D:\Program Files\PuTTY\;d:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\;D:\android\sdk;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Roaming\npm
18 verbose lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~install: CWD: C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\node_modules\node-sass
19 silly lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~install: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node scripts/install.js' ]
20 silly lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~install: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
21 info lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~postinstall: node-sass@3.13.0
22 verbose lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
23 verbose lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~postinstall: PATH: C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;D:\ANDROID\SDK;D\PYTHON27\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;D:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;D:\Program Files\PuTTY\;d:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\;D:\android\sdk;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Roaming\npm
24 verbose lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~postinstall: CWD: C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k\node_modules\node-sass
25 silly lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~postinstall: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node scripts/build.js' ]
26 silly lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~postinstall: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
27 info lifecycle node-sass@3.13.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
28 verbose stack Error: node-sass@3.13.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
28 verbose stack Exit status 1
28 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
28 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
28 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
28 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
28 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
28 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
28 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
28 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
29 verbose pkgid node-sass@3.13.0
30 verbose cwd C:\Users\claud_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.13.0\plugin.compileScssBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScssBatch\node_modules\.temp-172cf4k.ow7k
31 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.10586
32 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\claud_000\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.6.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\claud_000\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.6.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "rebuild" "--update-binary"
33 verbose node v8.8.1
34 verbose npm  v5.4.2
35 error code ELIFECYCLE
36 error errno 1
37 error node-sass@3.13.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
37 error Exit status 1
38 error Failed at the node-sass@3.13.0 postinstall script.
38 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue re-compiling node-sass for the new node version. Have you tried a `meteor reset`?

You should also try

```
meteor remove fourseven:scss
meteor add fourseven:scss
```

To get a fresh install of the problem module